# How to loop through a table and perform an action on a row

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, datatable

I would like to loop through a table to calculate the percent change (between each row and the previous row). That result would then the put into a new column. This is the code so far:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(new_table)) {
  prev_row <-  i - 1
  new_table$new_col[i] == 
    (new_table$old_col[i] - new_table$old_col[prev_row]) / new_table$old_col[prev_row]
  }
```

An example input table and the expected output table would be:

```
 new_table (pre-loop)             new_table (post-loop)
      Year   Price                Year   Price  Pct_Chg
  [1] 1999    10              [1] 1999    10       -
  [2] 2000    11              [2] 2000    11      10.0
  [3] 2001    12              [3] 2001    12       9.1
  [4] 2002    11              [4] 2002    11      -8.3
```

I have tried a few different versions although have yet to do it. Either due to the curly brackets (do actions performed to a vector exist outside of the curly brackets?) or the square brackets (the way it assigns values versus using variables as pointers, such as say you reference the previous row you would expect the code to be something along the lines of current_row[i - 1] although I am not sure thats correct).

Thank you in advance for any guidance / help / corrections!

Comment: R is oriented around vectorized calculations so it's more idiomatic to do this without a loop, e.g. `new_table$Pct_Chg = new_table$Price / lag(new_table$Price) - 1`

Comment: ^ That means, make a new `Pct_Chg` column in the data frame, for which each value is the respective Price divided by the prior Price (NA for first row) minus one. R can compile that once and run it on all rows at once, instead of interpreting it for each row. https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/